# Differentiability of function $f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dudv}{1 + u^2 +v^2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I need to see if $f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dudv}{1 + u^2 +v^2}$ where $(x,y) \in (0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ is differentiable. If i set $g(v,y) =\int_{0}^{y}\frac{du}{1 + u^2 +v^2}$ then i have $f(x,y) = \int_{0}^{x} g(v,y)dv$. I have then $\frac{∂f}{∂x}=g(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{du}{1 + u^2 +x^2}$ and i have  $\frac{∂f}{∂y}=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{∂g}{∂y}dv=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dv}{1 + y^2 +v^2}$. Now since domain of $f$ is an open set and partial derivatives $\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ and  $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ exits and are continuous for all $(x,y) \in (0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ function $f$ is differentiable at every point of domain. Is this solution correct?

Comment: As long as you know why $\int_{0}^{y}\frac{du}{1 + u^2 +x^2}$ is a continuous function of $(x,y)$, I'd say you're in good shape.